# Is it possible to obtain a value from another process?

Tags: pointers, rust

I have this script written in rust that grabs the raw pointer of an initialized  `u8` value, prints the address of that pointer, then basically goes on pause waiting for a user input.

```rs
fn main() {
    //  Initialize `x` as raw pointer of `u8` value `43`
    let x = &mut (43 as u8) as *mut u8;

    println!("{:?}", x);

    //  Wait for user input so that `x` stays in place
    drop(std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut String::new()));
}
```

The script above runs, prints the address of  where `x` is being stored, then goes to "sleep", leaving `x` at that specific memory location.  I was wondering if it were possible to run another process and use that specific memory address to grab the value of `x`.  I used the following script that I wrote:

```rs
unsafe fn read<T>(addr: i64) -> &'static T {
    &*(addr as *mut T)
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", read::<u8>(0xe1110ff9ef))
    }
}
```

But it would always result with this error:
`error: process didn't exit successfully:` target\debug\t3.exe `(exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)`

Is this possible?

Comment: Addresses in memory rarely actually refer directly to addresses in RAM. Modern OSes use virtual memory: every process is associated with its own mapping from its virtual address space into real memory (and other OS supplied services). And in particular, different processes cannot by default see each other's memory because the OS simply does not allow them to (for security). Also, it's entirely possible that one address in one process is used for something else in another process, so if you do acquire some "shared memory" (as it's called) it'll generally appear at different addresses.

Comment: Why are you actually trying to do this? At it is, the answer is just "you can't", but if you focus your question a bit more on your goal instead of this as possible solution, it'll be easier for people to suggest alternatives.

Comment: @HTNW ahh that makes sense. thank you